# C++ istream - how to read string with whitespace

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream

in the following small program I want to read the inputString with whitespace:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


int main( int argc , char ** argv ) {
   std::string inputString(" ITEM ");
   std::istringstream inputStream( inputString );

   //Template:

   T value;

   inputStream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
   inputStream >> value;

   std::cout << "Value: [" << value << "]" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "StringPos: " << inputStream.tellg() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "State: " << inputStream.good() << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
Value: []
StringPos: -1
State: 0
```

If I remove the the unsetf() call I instead get:

```
Value: [ITEM]
StringPos: 4
State: 1
```

I.e. as expected when whitespace is ignored. So - obviously I do something wrong with the "Don't skip whitespace" setting. Any tips?

Edit: After adding the template-like "T value" the example does not compile any longer; but it is important that the

```
inputStream >> value;
```

works. The following meta code should work as well:

```
if is_string(T)
   value = inputString;   // String values are assigned directly
else 
   inputStream >> value;  // Other types.
```

Joakim

Comment: i think you are looking for `std::getline()`

Comment: Apparently extracting a `string` from a stream when `skipws` is false fails.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
std::string line;
if(std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
    // line contains one line from the input stream
} else {
    // inputStream is empty, EOF or in error state
}
```

Comment: Thanks but; the code I posted illustrates the problem - but I really need

Comment: Don't think this will work. The code is templated - see update.

Comment: @user422005 - try `inputStream.setf(std::noskipws);` or `inputStream >> std::noskipws >> value;` instead (I'm not sure about this).